# Modify object property with a variable in typescript

Tags: typescript

In js I have a function which modify properties of an object contained in a list of object according to parameters:

```
function edit(object, key, property, value){
  object[key][property] = value;
}
```

How would I manage to do the same function in TypeScript ?

From now I've made this:

```
function edit(object: ObjectList, key: string, property: string, value: number){
  object[key][property] = value;
}
```

But that doesn't work and gives me a `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ name: string; mastery: number; parent_skill: number; access_level: number; cost: string; cost_value: number; background_color: number[]; font_color: number[]; description: string; required_skills: number[]; }'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ name: string; mastery: number; parent_skill: number; access_level: number; cost: string; cost_value: number; background_color: number[]; font_color: number[]; description: string; required_skills: number[]; }'`

I want to be able to call the function like this:

```
edit(myObject, "first", "oneProperty", "newValue1");
```

And the result would be that my "first" item in myObject would have "newValue1" for its "oneProperty" property.

More informations:
My object list

```
type SkillList = {
  [key: string]: Skill;
};
```

My object

```
type Skill = {
  name: string;
  mastery: number;
  parent_skill: number;
  access_level: number;
  cost: string;
  cost_value: number;
  background_color: number[];
  font_color: number[];
  description: string;
  required_skills: number[];
};
```

Comment: It gives you a... what exactly? Seems you missed pasting the error.

Comment: Also, what type signature does `ObjectList` have?

Comment: Thanks @CherryDT I edited.

Comment: @CherryDT When you said 'You need a type limited to the values existing in the object', do you refer to the Skill object or the SkillList ? Do you mean that a String litteral Types should handle the job ?

Comment: `Skill`, but I deleted the comment because I thought it would make more sense to wait for someone more competent in TypeScript than me to write an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer would be a generic function:

### The Code

```
function edit<O extends ObjectList, K extends keyof O, P extends keyof O[K]>(object: O, key: K, property: P, value: O[K][P]){
  object[key][property] = value;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=42#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwCYygHgPIoB5TJioDOi2ARgFbLQAyMJUANIgNL6HFkDWyAnnGDlWABU5FSiPoOHYA2mwC6APgAUcarSgAuEdIF62rAA4AnOCeRmo-PaNYA3AIYAbEMj0Ll80UoCUAN4AsABQiIiaNNDyMkry5pbWtkqIALyILu7IANxhAL5hYbZW5Fr0jFDpiCHhEYixhohMZjBgAOZKeoH5eaGFocX8pQDKPDCurgxM1bURjXbNUK0dXYhjE659vUWhJcjr45OzYRFgzgC2nksr7X0RF85M1otgIBcU1veIJs5mRFAAPokI6uPRvD5fU6IZwQCDIEgkQGuZCOZBgxAQz5mb4QOBMPQtNp3aF4piArIecHvbHfCiwnjtCzgVCAvGuOBmamQszyJTfYAIIHsznc7F876oBEQVomWAIQnLYnff4ARxAMH+rJBmxIYusEoKfTCaAwah6MLIG0m0xYiAARABGe2se3nK4uh2OgBMAGZ7f4gA)

### Explanation

First, we have a generic type `O` which lets us use the inputed object type, e.g. to potentially narrow `[key: string]: Skill;`.

Then we have generic type `K` which refers to all of the keys in `O`/`object`.

After that we have generic type `P` which refers to all the properties in `object[key]`.

Finally we have `O[K][P]` which tells typescript to use the type of `object[key][property]`. This is probably the most useful part, since it prevents overriding `string`s with `number`s, for example `edit(mySkillObject, "first", "name", "newValue1");`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanations. It's definitely what I needed to move forward !